# Can't create test in VS2013, no Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting namespace

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, vs-unit-testing-framework

I'm new to C#, .NET and VS; using VS 2013 Ultimate. I'm trying to create a unit test using what seems to be the "VS way" but can't figure it out.

It looks like the culprit is that I don't have access to the Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Assert method or enclosing namespace... I've looked all around and can't find any references to this namespace. Is this something extra I need to install? At this point I have no idea what to look for.

I'm working around it with additional Main methods, which is a huge PITA...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

welcome to .NET development!

By default, Visual Studio will add references to the most common namespaces/classes to your project when the project is created. TestTools.UnitTesting is not one of those namespaces, so you'll have to add a reference to the file where it lives, which is in `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll`.

Check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13602508/where-to-find-microsoft-visualstudio-testtools-unittesting-missing-dll) for how to add references (I think your question duplicates it):

Comment: That thread worked perfectly to get the namespace into my solution. I added TestClass and TestMethod annotations. Now to get the Test Explorer to realize they're there... Thanks.

Edit: I had them static to work with my Main; they work now, yay!

Answer (score 3):

You need a reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll in your project. It's installed with VS so you should have it listed in the Add Reference dialog.
But the correct way would be to create project from "Unit Test" template that will add the reference in advance.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know the correct way, I'll look into adding another project. This one-method app is probably too simple but it's good to know.

Answer (score 1):

For VS2013, add reference to

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll
```

from

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies
```