# Can I use visual studio unit test framework with Visual Studio Community?

Tags: unit-testing

For the life of me, I cannot figure out how to add Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting to my project in Visual Studio 2013 Community version.

I tried adding it through nuget, which doesn't work -- I can only find Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestingFramework, which seems to be different.

I tried adding it from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\ (as mentioned here [Where to find "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting" missing dll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13602508/)), but that directory doesn't exist for me.

I'm kind of at a loss now.  Can I not use that with the community version of visual studio?

Comment: Why don't you just create a new Unit Test project?

Answer (score 1):

I had this today after uninstalling older VS products.  I had VS2012 Express and VS2013 Professional installed, as well as using VS2015 Community Edition.

I'm afraid I don't have an explanation, but creating a new Unit Test project, recreating references and copying the code from the old Unit Test project has sorted out the issue.  There must be something under the hood that changed.

I hope that helps someone else if they find themselves in the same boat!