# Reference Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework for CI build

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015

I have created a C# test project in VS2015 RC. it builds locally but when i attempt to build on our CI build server (TeamCity) it fails with errors:

> UnitTest1.cs(2,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name
>   'VisualStudio' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you
>   missing an assembly reference?)
>   [... .Tests.csproj]
>   UnitTest1.cs(9,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name
>   'TestMethod' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or
>   an assembly reference?)
>   [... .Tests.csproj]

Clearly this is because the assembly containing these namespaces (`Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework`) is not on the build server; on my local machine it resides at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll`.

I could copy the assembly into my solution so that it becomes part of the codebase but manually moving files feels like a bit of an inelegant hack. I searched around on nuget and found http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework/ which I figured would do the trick, but installing that package failed with:

> Install-Package : Could not install package
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework 11.0.50727.1'.
>   You are trying to install this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETFramework, Version=v4.5.2', but the  package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework

What's my best option of solving this? I'm surprised that creating a test project in VS2015 does not automatically include all the dependencies that I need, though perhaps I'm being naive (I'm something of a fledgling dot netter).

Comment: Why on earth would someone mark this down? Its a perfectly valid question. I'm an inexperienced .net developer who, after spending some considerable time googling and not getting anywhere, is looking for some guidance as to how to progress. Is SO so elitist that I'm not allowed to do that? Seriously?

Comment: @jaimiet I had the same problem, on your TeamCity Agent are you building under Mono on Linux? Mono doesn't provide that library as part of it's distribution. If it's .NET under Windows, you have a few options for getting it in place.

Answer (score 7):

The answer is similar to option 1 in [eng.augusto's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30595283/reference-microsoft-visualstudio-qualitytools-unittestframework-for-ci-build/32363849#32363849).
Microsoft doesn't provide NuGet for the latest version of `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework,`
 but rather supplies it as a part of Visual Studio 
([normally at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13602508/where-to-find-microsoft-visualstudio-testtools-unittesting-missing-dll) `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll`)

I created the folder `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools` as a subfolder of my solution and copied:

Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll
Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.xml

The files should be added to source control (even if DLLs are usually ignored).
Then I changed references in my Test.csproj to refer to a new location.

Answer (score 5):

Hmm I have some ideas, so choose the one that best fits your needs

1. A simple answer should be mark the DLL to copy local and use a folder like Assemblies in the same folder of the solution and references "Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll"
2. Install Visual Studio in your build server. Sounds nuts but it's the closest to "developer machine" that you have.
3. Install the [DLL in the GAC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560649.aspx) so you don't have to bother with this.
4. Fix the NuGet package (Adding a reference for the .NET Framework version) and use it.
5. Downgrade your .NET Framework version so you can use the NuGet package.
6. Create your own NuGet server! (and add the reference of the DLLs you need).

IMHO I'd choose the first answer, because it seems to be the "best way" to use NuGet to resolve all your packages problems but you are using a DLL that you don't know if it should be trusted.

In system used in "old" languages like C, or C++ it's common you download the source code and the libraries needed for the code to run so I do not think the NuGet package it's the best solution.

Using the first option you always have the same version and could check the MD5 of the file and know exactly what is running in your build server.

Maybe the real best option should be 6. When you use your own NuGet server to handle your DLLs making your live more awesome and trustable.

Comment: Or you avoid all that horror by using xunit, nunit... anything not from microsoft.

Comment: I came across this problem in a couple of projects I have own which actually use NUnit  with but some references came along with some of the test projects. I didn't realise until I dropped them into our TeamCity system.

Answer (score 3):

For projects created in VS 2017. Adding Nuget package Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.Updated allows to build unit test projects on CI without VS installed on build server:

[image]

Comment: This package has been unlisted:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.Updated/

Comment: For 15.0 this is currently available: https://www.nuget.org/packages/VS.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework/15.0.27323.2
Even though many of these packages claim to be "created by" Microsoft, the owner is usually some random person, so I'm not sure about licensing concerns.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this issue when trying to use MSBuild on our dev server via our CI/CD process after I was asked to uninstall VS2013 from our dev server by our IT team.

In my case in my build output there were a few lines with the word **Considered**. What this means is that the build is *considering* those folders for locations where the file may be located. One of those lines was as follows:

```
Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll", but it didn't exist.
```

I copied **Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll** from my local machine to that folder on the dev server and the error went away.

Answer (score 1):

Of course Microsoft does a s...t job. To fix this, you need to copy the dll's to some convinint lication and reference them from your ptoject .csproj file.

```
    <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
      <Reference Include="QualityTools-Fakes">
        <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.dll</HintPath>
      </Reference>
    </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
```

I don't understand why when we add this from VSudio it does not update the same file instead no one has an idea what it does. In Java you have a single file pom.xml or build.gradle, nothing else. In C# there is all sorts of stuff which adds no value but confusion.