# NUnit Assert method error as it is found in NUnit.Framework and Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting namespace as well

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

If I am using both statements at the same time

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using NUnit.Framework;
```

I get an error for `Assert` method. Could someone tell me what is the best way of using it.

Should I replace each `Assert` method with the following?

```
NUnit.Framework.Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, result);
```

Comment: Why do you have using directives for both frameworks? I would suggest you pick *one* framework and stick to it.

Comment: I was trying to use `[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]` which is inside `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting`

Comment: I'd strongly advise against using that to start with. Use `Asset.Throws` instead, which tests that *exactly* the piece of code you expect to throw an exception actually throws it.

Comment: NUnit used to have ExpectedException in 2.x (like MSTest still has).  If you have the opportunity to pick between MSTest and NUnit I would definitely pick NUnit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Jon Skeet mentions in his comment, you should only be using one test framework. They will not play nicely together. If you want to use NUnit, you should,

1. Remove all of your `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting` using statements.
2. Remove the reference to `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework` from your project references.

Your unit tests will only end up running under one of the test adapters, MSTest or NUnit. The asserts for each test framework throw different exceptions on assert failures and each test runner expects its own exceptions to be thrown. If you try to use an MSTest assert in your tests and your test fails, NUnit will not recognize the exception thrown as an assertion exception, so it will report it as an error as opposed to a test failure.

You likely ended up with both test frameworks because you created a **Unit Test Project** in Visual Studio, then added NUnit to it. NUnit test projects should just be a regular **Class Library**. Another option is to install the [NUnit Templates Extension for Visual Studio](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6cd55f79-4936-49e7-b81d-c40fcd81abc7) which will add an **NUnit 3 Unit Test Project** template to Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can either decide to use NUnit or the built-in Visual Studio Unit Testing DLL.

**NUnit**
If you want to use NUnit, and it sounds like you already have the NUnit NuGet package installed, you simply comment out the line:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
```

If you want to really remove the native Visual Studio Unit Testing from your project, you could delete that line and remove your reference to `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll`.  This should not be required, but it could prevent any of those "ambiguous reference" errors that could possibly occur.

**Visual Studio Tools**
If you wanted to use the Visual Studio native tools, however, you'd want to go to the NuGet Package Manager, find the NUnit package, and select to uninstall it and click OK on the prompt.  It would proceed to remove the NUnit DLLs and dependencies.  You would remove the

```
using NUnit.Framework;
```

line manually from the top of your Unit Test class. You would need to ensure you have the Visual Studio Unit Testing DLL referenced.  If you don't have it already referenced, you'd need to go to **References > Add References** and browse to it.  Its location can vary depending on the Visual Studio version you have.  I answered a question on that, here:

[Where to find "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting" missing dll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13602508/where-to-find-microsoft-visualstudio-testtools-unittesting-missing-dll/51972938#51972938)