# Can a C# MsTest project be converted to Microsoft.NET.Sdk project format?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

I've got a C# MsTest project that targets net48. I've change the project it tests to the newer style Microsoft.NET.Sdk csproj format and that went ok. Now I want to convert the unit test project too.

I get errors about namespace Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting cannot be found: `error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'VisualStudio' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'`

To solve that, I added the assembly reference to the csproj:

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

But I get errors that it can't be found.
`warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.`

This was found ok when the old csproj format was used.

How can I get this assembly reference to be found, or what is the preferred way of making this work?

Comment: Did you try [MSTest.TestFramework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSTest.TestFramework/) package?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where to find "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting" missing dll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13602508/where-to-find-microsoft-visualstudio-testtools-unittesting-missing-dll) Seems to be an exact duplicate

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Thanks for the link. No it didn't answer the question, I've effectively tried the first answer there, but I'm using a different project format and the assembly can't be resolved.

Comment: @Pavel I tried a different package, I'm having more success with MSTest.TestFramework. It now builds, thanks.

Comment: I'm now just having this issue: Starting test execution, please wait...
         Test run will use DLL(s) built for framework .NETFramework,Version=v4.0 and platform X64. Following DLL(s) do
         not match framework/platform settings.
         MyTest.VsTests.dll is built for Framework .NETFramework,Version=v4.8 and Platform AnyCPU.

Comment: Ok, I also added package MSTest.TestAdapter and it now works

Comment: Yes, test adapter is needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 3 possible solutions:

1. Upgrade to MSTestV2 by adding the nuget packages `MSTest.Framework` and `MSTest.TestAdapter`.

- **CAVEAT:** `MSTestV2` only supports .NET Framework 4.5 and later.

2. Continue using MSTestV1 by helping visual studio find the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll` reference, by adding this to your csproj:
   `<PropertyGroup><AssemblySearchPaths></AssemblySearchPaths></PropertyGroup>`

- see [this explanation](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/2920) for why that's necessary

3. Continue using MSTestV1 by browsing to the dll's path when adding the reference to `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll`

- Depending on your version of VS the path will be something like: `Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies`

I used #2 because we target net40 and have multiple developers working on different versions of VS.

Answer (score 1):

Add the nuget packages [MSTest.TestFramework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSTest.TestFramework/) and [MSTest.TestAdapter](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSTest.TestAdapter/).

The test framework allows the unit tests to build and brings in the required namespaces. The second allows the test runner to find the tests in the project.

Comment: The nuget packages you linked to are MSTestV2 but `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework` is MSTestV1.